# CSS: padding doesn't let element go fully top

Tags: html, css

I was making navigator menu for my website, i tried properly setting line-height and height for navigator menu, where i got the problem, the `profilebar` element was too low and so was the `balance` paragraph.

Navigator menu style:

```
.menu {
  background-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.7em;
  line-height: 3.7em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 102.5%;
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

---

[Fiddle Fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/mrycuncp/embedded/result/) ( Image is sample, so it being bigger than menu is not problem. The picture i originally use is 32x32 image from steam API ).

[Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/mrycuncp/1/).

What could the problem be? is it padding that i need to properly set? or are there other things that i have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try resize your profile picture: set height for .profilepicture
and set margin and padding for .balance 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

that is all

Comment: In post i mentioned that profile picture was just sample, it is way more little originally, 32x32 from API, and `.balance` is position relative.

Comment: Problem is with p (paragraph element). In bootstrap it has margin and padding. Therefor it goes down. 
Simply change image to 32x32px, and add margin and padding as i mentioned. everything will be ok

Comment: dont foget to change line-height for .profilebar **line-height: 1;** 
check at https://jsfiddle.net/mrycuncp/3/